# Java явное и неявное приведение целочисленного литерала к byte в операторе присваивания и вызове функции

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос заключается в следующем. В записи `byte a = 5` литерал 5 является типом int, но явно приводить его к меньшему типу byte не нужно, так как компилятор автоматически следит за тем, входит ли число в диапазон значений byte. В то же время при вызове метода `f(byte a)` с использованием литерала `f(5)`, компилятор выдает ошибку, так как требуется явное приведение типов из int к byte. Почему в случае присваивания явное приведение типов не нужно, а при вызове метода - нужно?

Пример кода:

```
public class Main {
    public static void f(byte a){
        System.out.println("byte");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte a = 6;//works fine
        f(a);//works fine
        f(5);//doesn't work
        f((byte)5);//works fine
    

    }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про полиморфизм функций.

Comment: Если вы создадите ф-ю `f(int a)`, то вызываться будет именно она, а не как ранее задумывалось - `f(byte a)`. Точно сказать, не могу, но считаю, что дело в этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // В данном случае есть однозначность при приведении типов
        double d = 123.4;
        float f = 123.4f;
        long l = 123L;
        int i = 123;
        short s = 123;
        byte b = 123;

        // методы в Java требуют более явного указания типа, т.к. методы могут быть перегружены
        f(123); // будет использован метод f(int), т.к. 123 имеет тип int
        f(123L); // будет использован метод f(long), т.к. суффикс "L" указывает на тип long
        f(123.4f); // будет использован метод f(float), т.к. суффикс "f" указывает на тип float
        f(123.4); // будет использован метод f(double), т.к. число с плавающей точкой (без суффикса "f") указывает на тип double

        // при передаче переменной в качестве аргумента будет использован метод строго с типом данной переменной
        f(d); // будет использован метод f(double), т.к. тип переменной "d" явно на это указывает
        f(f); // будет использован метод f(float), т.к. тип переменной "f" явно на это указывает
        f(l); // будет использован метод f(long), т.к. тип переменной "l" явно на это указывает
        f(i); // будет использован метод f(int), т.к. тип переменной "i" явно на это указывает
        f(s); // будет использован метод f(short), т.к. тип переменной "s" явно на это указывает
        f(b); // будет использован метод f(byte), т.к. тип переменной "b" явно на это указывает

        // но ничего не мешает сделать явное преобразование типов
        f((byte) l); // значение переменной l типа long явно преобразовано к типу byte, поэтому будет вызван метод f(byte)
        f((int) 123.3); // число типа double явно преобразовано к типу int, поэтому будет вызван метод f(int)
    }

    public static void f(double d) {
        System.out.println("double");
    }

    public static void f(float f) {
        System.out.println("float");
    }

    public static void f(long l) {
        System.out.println("long");
    }

    public static void f(int i) {
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public static void f(short s) {
        System.out.println("short");
    }

    public static void f(byte b) {
        System.out.println("byte");
    }

}
```